# Should I utilize Flux way in React webapp if i have no need to store data?

Tags: reactjs, flux

For example, I need to validate email during registration process (check, if it already exists in database). In this case i have no need to store any data.
Should i utilize flux way and call server side (nodejs) api through Actions or just call server side api right from the registration form component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling the server I would go through actions , receive the answer call dispatch and put it in a simple store where your email status become "verified" instead of "unverified".

Store is not only storing things but keeping your data workflow states updated.

Just my opinion but I would do that. It will be cleared to do like that to master your data flow in the future.